# Binary cannot find shared object that's present on my machine

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dynamic-linking

Riddle me this:

```
$ obs
obs: error while loading shared libraries: libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ sudo apt install libdouble-conversion1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdouble-conversion1 is already the newest version (2.0.1-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.

$ dpkg -L libdouble-conversion1                                                                    ✘ 127 
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libdouble-conversion1
/usr/share/doc/libdouble-conversion1/README
/usr/share/doc/libdouble-conversion1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libdouble-conversion1/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1

$ ldd $(which obs) | grep double
    libdouble-conversion.so.1 => not found

$ ldd $(which obs) | head
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdf8323000)
    libobs-frontend-api.so.0 => /usr/lib/libobs-frontend-api.so.0 (0x00007f67ba8bc000)
    libavcodec.so.58 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58 (0x00007f67b93c4000)
    libavutil.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.56 (0x00007f67b9346000)
    libavformat.so.58 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58 (0x00007f67b90ee000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f67b906b000)
    libQt5X11Extras.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5X11Extras.so.5 (0x00007f67b9064000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f67b8a0a000)
    libobs.so.0 => /usr/lib/libobs.so.0 (0x00007f67b893f000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f67b83d4000)
```

I've had a similar issue more than once on this machine. Why is it refusing to link with the `libdouble-conversion.so.1` file that's clearly present on my machine?

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1 obs`?

Comment: `ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

Comment: Bingo... looks like despite being listed as an installed file it wasn't present. A forced reinstall of the `libdouble-conversion1` package did the trick!